# what does the 1233 behind the colon represents in www.happy.com:1233

Tags: content-management-system, vs-web-site-project

I am planning to set up a Content Management System which is entirely owned by myself. I encountered someone who could help me do so, but I realised that the developer created something with the following site: www.happy.com:1234.

Does it mean that 1233 is a database and that the entire website/server is still owned by developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the URL

```
www.happy.com:1233
```

The number `1233` is the *port* to which your browser is attempting to connect.  Perhaps unbeknownst to you, in order to connect to a server, we need *both* an IP address and a *port*.  Here, the IP address will be resolved using the website name `www.happy.com`.

Comment: in this regard, I am considered to be renting a port instead of purchasing a CMS. Am I right?  I would liken it to wordpress where wordpress owns the rights and I pay a monthly subscription fee in order to continue using it. I am concerned that if www.happy.com closes, then similarly whichever data I have in the port will close too.

Comment: The port is merely an entry point, at least from the point of view of renting space from Wordpress.  If they deny you access to the site, it means that the site and port will not be available.